# Is there any significance to the "C-15" seen in What If episode 1?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvels-what-if

In *What If...?* episode 1, the non-super-solder Steve Rogers ends up as the pilot of a proto-Iron Man suit built by Howard Stark.  The suit has "C-15" painted on its left breast, and a star on the right one.

The MCU has a long-running tradition of throwing in little shout-outs to comic history here and there, especially with things like identification numbers or names.  This feels like exactly the sort of place where that would happen.  Is "C-15" a reference to something from Marvel Comics history?

Comment: Looking at the comics isn't much help. [_Captain America Comics Vol. 1_ 15](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Comics_Vol_1_15) doesn't really have a matching storyline. [_Captain America Vol. 1_ 115](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_115) does have a relevant storyline, however, it is issue 115 not 15. The storyline is about Red Skull and the Cosmic Cube.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot C is the Roman Numeral for 100. Is that too obscure?

Comment: @OrangeDog Could do, but then it's having a double meaning as well.

Comment: It can be a reference to Agent Carter live action show which came in 2015.